# Unable to see results with AsyncTypeahead with multiple option and renderInput

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use a custom Input component on a Typeahead with the `multiple` option set. I see in the docs it says to "handle the refs" correctly, but I see no examples of how this is done. I'm not sure what to pass into `referenceElementRef`. Everything I've tried so far just doesn't render the options as I type. I see them in the DOM, but the `opacity` of the `.rbt-menu` is set to 0, so they're basically hidden.

Here's my code so far:

```
const divRef = React.useRef(null);
  return (
    <Col>
      <div ref={divRef}>
        <span className="uppercase">
          <FormattedMessage id="d.customer" defaultMessage="Customer" tagName="h4" />
        </span>
        <AsyncTypeahead
          multiple
          id="customer-filter-input"
          inputProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Customer search',
            style: { fontSize: '14px' },
          }}
          key={'customer-input'}
          minLength={4}
          isLoading={props.isLoadingcustomersSuggestions}
          delay={300}
          onSearch={(term: string) => handleFilterInputs(term, 'customers')}
          size={'lg'}
          options={dataSource}
          labelKey={'defaultMessage'}
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'companyName',
            defaultMessage: 'Company name',
          })}
          onChange={(filterItem: any) => handleAutocompleteUpdate(filterItem, 'customer')}

          renderInput={({ inputRef, referenceElementRef, ...inputProps }: any) => (
            <Input
              {...inputProps}
              style={{ position: 'relative' }}
              ref={(input: any) => {
                inputRef(input);
                referenceElementRef(divRef); // What do I put here?
              }}
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>

    </Col>
  );
```

And this is what renders in the DOM after I type in the Typeahead and get results: [image]

Any ideas or working examples of Typeahead using multiple and renderInput together?

**EDIT**:
Here's a codesandbox of what I'm seeing. I also see that the problem is also happening when `multiple` is NOT set. It seems to be an issue with using `renderInput`. Is it required that I also use `renderMenu`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-async-pagination-example-forked-3kz3z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade the typeahead version in your sandbox to the latest version (v5.1.1) and pass the `input` element to `referenceElementRef`, it works (note that you need to type some characters into the input for the menu to appear):

```js
// v5.0 or later
renderInput={({ inputRef, referenceElementRef, ...inputProps }) => (
  <Input
    {...inputProps}
    ref={(input) => {
      inputRef(input);
      referenceElementRef(input);
    }}
  />
)}
```

The menu is rendered in relation to the `referenceElementRef` node by `react-popper`. In most common cases, the reference node will be the input itself. The reason there's both an `inputRef` and a `referenceElementRef` is for more complex cases (like multi-selection) where the menu needs to be rendered in relation to a container element around the input.

If using v4 of the component, the approach is similar, but the ref to use is simply called `ref`:

```js
// v4
renderInput={({ inputRef, ref, ...inputProps }) => (
  <Input
    {...inputProps}
    ref={(input) => {
      inputRef(input);
      ref(input);
    }}
  />
)}
```

Comment: Ah right, right after I posted this question I realized the version was pretty behind. I also realized that some of the markup and styling of my custom Input I was using in `renderInput` was the reason why I couldn't see the results. Now the issue is when I click on a suggestion, it doesn't show up in the input. I've updated the above sandbox. Try selecting a suggestion and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @MarquesWoodson: That's because you have `multiple` set to `true`. When you make a selection in that case, the input value is set to `''`. The selections are available as a property in the second arg of `renderInput` and you need to handle those separately. See a very simple example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-typeahead-async-pagination-example-forked-689fg

Comment: Aaaah gotcha. I figured that I had to handle them myself, i just couldnt find an example in the docs that showed how, or maybe I overlooked it. This makes sense though. Thank you for the help :)